# Checking to see if the password matches the particular user- PostgreSQL and Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to implement a section of code which checks that the  hashed_password and user_name match. The code below first checks to see if the username is valid, then if valid the code will then check to see if the password matches the username. However, that is section of the code that is not working. I can enter the correct username from the database and the corresponding correct password from the database and it displays the correct message `You can proceed!`. But if I enter the correct username from the database but an incorrect password it still displays `You can proceed!`. Any help is appreciated!

```
public void letsLogin() throws SQLException
 {

  System.out.print("Enter your user name: ");
  username = in.next();


  sql = "SELECT " + "username " + "FROM" + " users_table" + " where username = "
        + "'" + username + "'";


  result = s.executeQuery(sql);

 // select hashed_password
  sql_hash = "SELECT " + "hashed_password = " + "crypt(" + "'"
                 + hashed_password + "'" + ","+ "hashed_password)" +
                 " as matched " + "from users_table" +  " where username = "
                 + "'" + username + "'";

 result2 = s2.executeQuery(sql_hash);

  if(result.next())
  {
        System.out.println("You are registered!");
         // ask user to enter password

        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        hashed_password = stdin2.next();

        // check to see if username and hashed_password match
        if(result2.next())
        {
           System.out.println("You can proceed!");
        }

        else
        {
           System.exit(0);
        }


  }
```

Comment: Why you are not using one query?

Comment: Never insert user input directly into your SQL query. You are giving the user the opportunity to do anything they want in your database. You should use a prepared statement with parameters. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Please, please, use prepared statements. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Also, realize you're passing the hashed_password to the query before you ask the user to enter it. This makes no sense. You're not even using the entered password anywhere. And why would the user ever enter a hashed password?

Comment: @YCF_L Because I have to first check the username and if no username doesn't exist then user must register. Once I have checked the username then I can can check username and password match

Comment: You could do a join on the `users` and `users_table` tables. That way, you need only one query. Also, why on earth do you concatenate the SQL strings that way? It's unreadable.

Comment: @SeverityOne Sorry I didn't copy everything from the code. The password and username are both saved in the same table, users_table.

Comment: As the instructions say, give a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to analyze why this code is not working, because it must be rewritten from scratch due to SQL Injection vulnerability.
Consider what happens when someone will enter this username:

```
' or 1=1 or 'x' = '
```

The first query becomes:

```
SELECT username FROM users_table where username = '' or 1=1 or 'x' = '';
```

The second query becomes:

```
 SELECT hashed_password =  crypt('any string', anything) as matched 
 from users where username = '' or 1=1 or 'x' = '';
```

In this case both queries always return some rows.
Because your code checks only a result of `resultset.next()` call, all checks will always pass, and .... the attacker logs into the system knowing neither the username nor the password.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I currently don't have to worry about the SQL injection attacks

Comment: @AbbyS yes you have to. Learn how to do things well from the start. Don't be sloppy. And it will make your code more readable, too. And it won't crash if there is a quote in a user name or a password.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, it is best to use `PrepardStatement` and to create separate function to check the username and password.